# Rails 3.1 in production mode saves model to database but returns id zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Hello!
It is happening a very weird thing when I save a model in rails 3.1

**Same project in development / production**

There is a simple model City with 2 fields (name / state).

**development console**

```
city = City.new(:name => "Sao Paulo", :uf => "SP")
city.save (true, no validations errors and record is created in database)
```

if I call "city.id", I get real value of ID saved in database, e.g. 123.
It is working fine in development.

**production console**

```
city = City.new(:name => "Sao Paulo", :uf => "SP")
city.save (true, no validations errors and record is created in database)
```

if I call "city.id", I get value equal 0 (different from value created automatically in database)

```
City.last (check if record is created in database...)
<City id: 22257, name: "Sao Paulo", uf: "SP", created_at: "2011-11-23 00:52:53", updated_at: "2011-11-23 00:52:53">
```

The record is created in database but not returns ID after call save/create. Did anyone see this before? This is the first time I see this behavior in production. It happens to every model in project. I used model City because it is the simplest one.
I am running rails 3.1.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you actually typing `city.id = 123` and `city.id = 0` on the console? If not, what specifically are you typing?

Comment: No, these values are the result when I type "city.id" to get the value. I am not setting them, just retrieving their values. I just type "city.id" (sorry if I was not clear in the question). The problem is the ID returned after call save or create methods. They return ID = zero in production.

Comment: What database are you using? Is it possible the table did not get set up and you do not have an auto-incrementing primary key like you should? I'm guessing this is a database/schema issue. If PostgreSQL you might be missing the sequence for your id column.

Comment: Carl -- I am using mysql server in production, but I was using sqlite3 in development. I changed to mysql in development and the behaviour occurs in this environment too. You could be right about being a database issue. I am using gems 'mysql' and 'ruby-mysql'. I will try to investigate any bug in these gems and then test with 'mysql2' gem. Thanks for the tip! I will update this post when I make any progress...

Comment: What do you get if, after you call `city.save`, you call `city.reload.id`?

Comment: I found the solution!!! I was using 'mysql' gem insted 'mysql2'. When I changed to mysql2 (in Gemfile and database.yml adapter), everything worked fine. It is probably an incompatibility issue betwen gem 'mysql' and rails 3.1. Thanks you all for help!

Comment: Could you add your solution as the correct answer and accept it for further reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!!! I was using 'mysql' gem insted 'mysql2'. When I changed to mysql2 (in Gemfile and database.yml adapter), everything worked fine. It is probably an incompatibility issue betwen gem 'mysql' and rails 3.1. Thanks you all for help!

Answer (score 1):

`city.id = 0` will not do anything to your database, it will only modify the instance you have of `City`, to actually write it to your database you should use `.save` on your instance after changing its attributes.

Also manually setting the value of a auto-increment unique sql column seems like asking for bad things to happen.

Also I think ids start with 1 and not 0, trying to put it to 0 will probably not be accepted by MySQL.

Comment: I updated the question. I think I was not very clear. I am not setting the value to ID, this is the value returned after call SAVE/CREATE.